# Laravel Homestead 12.1.0 still using php 8.0 unable to create Laravel 9 projects

Tags: laravel, homestead

I am trying to build a laravel 9 project through homestead but composer is failing since Laravel 9 requires 8.1.^

I removed my homestead box

```
vagrant box remove laravel/homestead
```

then added it again

```
vagrant box add laravel/homestead
```

but When i check in CLI,

```
 vagrant@homestead:~$ php -v
    PHP 8.0.1 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2021 08:22:35) ( NTS )
     Copyright (c) The PHP Group
     Zend Engine v4.0.1, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.0.1, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

I have homestead 12.1.0

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution. The issue was not with the box but instead with vagrant/homestead since I was running an older version.

I updated my vagrant/homestead on my machine to 13.2.1 and this fixed the problem.